# Grabbing a value from an input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to grab a value from an input field within jquery but I keep getting an undefined variable. The content is loaded dynamically so I need to use (this) and classes.

here is the html:

```
<div class="menu_page_container">
    <div class="page_link">NAME</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" class="page_id" />       
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".page_link").on('click', function () {
        var item_id = $(this).find(".page_id").attr("value");
        alert(item_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say the content has been loaded dynamically, do you mean the value or the `input` field itself?

Comment: I think he means the input field itself

Comment: The value, input field, and both the page_link div and menu_page_container divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). `siblings()` gets the siblings of a node by a given selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".page_link").on('click', function () {
        var item_id = $(this).siblings(".page_id").val();
        alert(item_id);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTEma/2/)